# Rethinkdb changesfeed in Express.js using thinky

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, scope, thinky

Created a basic express.js application and added a model (using thinky and rethinkdb) trying to pass the changesfeed to the jade file and unable to figure how to pass the results of the feed. My understanding is that changes() returns infinite cursor. So it is always waiting for new data. How to handle that in express res.  Any idea what am I missing here?

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var thinky = require('thinky')();
var type = thinky.type;
var r = thinky.r;

var User = thinky.createModel('User', {
    name: type.string()   
});
//end of thinky code to create the model


// GET home page. 
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var user = new User({name: req.query.author});
    user.save().then(function(result) {      
        console.log(result);
    });
    //User.run().then(function (result) {
        //res.render('index', { title: 'Express', result: result });
    //});
    User.changes().then(function (feed) {
        feed.each(function (err, doc) { console.log(doc);}); //pass doc to the res
        res.render('index', { title: 'Express', doc: doc}) //doc is undefined when I run the application. Why?
    });
    });
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that I believe you are facing is that `feed.each`is a loop that is calling the contained function for each item contained in the feed. So to access the `doc` contained in `console.log(doc)` you are going to need to either place your code in the function in which `doc` exists(is in the scope of the variable `doc`), or you are going to need to make a global variable to store doc value(s).

So for example, assuming `doc` is a string and that you wish to place all  `doc`'s in an array. You would need to start off by creating a variable which has a scope that `res.render` is in, which for this example will be `MYDOCS`. Then you would need to append each doc to it, and after that you would simply use MYDOC anytime you are attempting to access a doc outside of the `feed.each` function.

```
var MYDOCS=[];
User.changes().then(function (feed){
    feed.each(function (err, doc) { MYDOCS.push(doc)});
});
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var user = new User({name: req.query.author});
    user.save().then(function(result) {      
        console.log(result);
    });
    //User.run().then(function (result) {
        //res.render('index', { title: 'Express', result: result });
    //});
        res.render('index', { title: 'Express', doc: MYDOCS[0]}) //doc is undefined when I run the application. Why?
    });
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I appreciate taking the time to answer my question but it didn't work. doc still undefined. I'll have to look at integrating socket.io to pass it to the front.   I hope Express.js next version will think about real time updates from the db. It is an important feature that every new framework should consider.

Comment: @marco If you add console.log MYDOCS right before res.render do you get an output?

Comment: Yes. But that is the same issue I had before.

Comment: I think i may have misinterpreted the question. Are you attempting to add all changes for the life of the application to res? or just the changes that occur during the page request?

Comment: Yes, the life of the application (live updates to be pushed to the user dashboard) not during the page request.  My fault. Didn't explain the end goal.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect your clarification of the question, if the code above does not work please be as descriptive of the problem as possible, thank you for your time

Comment: Works. Thanks. So you create the global var and assign the output to it.